# Typescript: Function types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried some examples in the typescript handbook. More specifically, I stumbled across function types.

```
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}

interface SearchFunc {
  (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}

var mySearch: SearchFunc;

mySearch = function(subString: string) {
    var result = 1;
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I wonder why the above doesn't show me any errors. `mySearch` clearly doesn't follow the signature declared in the interface.

Comment: it clearly does follow the interface signature.